# How to create a DataFrame out of a list of strings with a varying amount of attributes per string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

Say I have a list of strings where each entry has a variable amount of 'attributes' and where the order may be different because of this.

```
str_list = ['id1 [first="jake" last="sully" hours="24"]',
            'id2 [first="bob" last="ross" job="painter" hours="11]']
```

How can I turn that list into a dataframe where if a string is missing an attribute it will just be blank in the df?

DataFrame would look like this (column order must be as shown below):

```
   id   first        job     last    hours
  id1    jake               sully       24 
  id2     bob    painter     ross       11
```

I know for id I can just split the string on ' [' and get the 0th index so that's not an issue.
For getting attribute items out of the string entry I know I can just use

```
test_list = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', str)
```

to get a list of values, but how would I build off of that to achieve my overarching goal with a varying amount of 'attributes'/messy order in each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

str_list = ['id1 [first="jake" last="sully" hours="24"]', 'id2 [first="bob" last="ross" job="painter" hours="11"]']

res = []
for item in str_list:
    current = {'id': re.findall('id\d+', item)[0]}
    for col in ['first', 'last', 'job', 'hours']:
        x = re.findall(f'{col}="(.*?)"', item)
        if x :
            current[col] = x[0]
            
    res.append(current)

pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Output:

```
    id first   last hours      job
0  id1  jake  sully    24      NaN
1  id2   bob   ross    11  painter
```

Comment: any way to keep it in order without manually re ordering after?

Comment: we can reorder columns after we create dataframe, dict is unordered

Comment: can you explain what  `current = {'id': re.findall('id\d+', item)[0]}` is doing?

as well as `x = re.findall(f'{col}="(.*?)"', item)`